# How to extract string from sentence using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, web-scraping, regex-group

I want to extract strings from the sentence using regex in R. And I'm new to R and don't where to begin or how to do it?

```
string<-c(".\n                Written by\nJ-S-Golden            \n        
\n        \n         \n                Plot Summary\n    |\n        Plot 
Synopsis\n    \n        \n            Plot Keywords:\n wrongful 
imprisonment\n                        |\n escape from prison\n                        
|\n based on the works of stephen king\n                        |\n 
prison\n                        |\n voice over narration\n            | See 
All (296) »      \n        \n            Taglines:\nFear can hold you 
prisoner. Hope can set you free.        \n        \n")
```

I have the string and I want in output is:

```
Plot Keywords:
\n wrongful imprisonment\n
|\n escape from prison\n
|\n based on the works of stephen king\n                        
|\n prison\n                        
|\n voice over narration\n            
| See All (296) »      \n        \n
```

I don't know how to extract clean data from the string. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Do you need the "\n" in the output as well?

Comment: @dylanjm No I don't need "\n" in output. But that's okay, I'm happy output came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution using base R's `sub` function.  This matches (and includes) the leading text `Plot Keywords:`.  Then, it uses a tempered dot to match any character until, but not including, the first following label followed by a colon.

```
sub("(?s).*(Plot Keywords:(?:(?![^: ]+:).)*).*", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)

[1] "Plot Keywords:\n wrongful \nimprisonment\n
                    |\n escape from prison\n
                    \n|\n based on the works of
     stephen king\n
                    |\n \nprison\n                        |\n voice over narration\n
        | See \nAll (296) »      \n        \n            "
```

In this particular case, a pure regex demo might be more helpful than a R demo, so here is a link to one:

### Demo

Comment: Thank you so much, you just gave perfect output i.e the required one, thanks a lot!